# What is this extra tuple from Popen in python?

Tags: python, popen

I'm a little confused on what's happening.  I want to count how many lines are returning to see if a process is running or not.  I'm using subprocess.Popen to run the command so I can get the output.  However, while testing my script, I'm seeing some additional output that I didn't count on and I'm just curious why and how to suppress it.

Here's a snippet from my script.  Please excuse any typos from me sanitizing it.

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen("ssh " + HOST + " ps -ef | grep jetty | wc -l", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

output = ssh.communicate()
print output
```

The output of this script is:

```
1
(None, None)
```

The docs say that communicate returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).  Why is it returning 1 and then (None, None)?  How do I suppress the (None, None) line/message?

Comment: Don't run this kind of stuff through the shell with subprocess.  It's not required, and will make your life more difficult.  Either use a proper Python ssh client e.g. paramiko, or automate the shell ssh using pexpect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get references to the command's standard output and/or standard error, you have to pass `subprocess.PIPE` as the value of the `stdout` and `stderr` (respectively) keyword arguments. Otherwise, a value of `None` is returned in the tuple. Since you didn't specify a value for `stdout`, the output of the command goes to your Python script's standard output, which is why you see "1".

Comment: ah, stupid me.  typo on my part and thx for pointing it out.  i was trying different things and forgot to change stdin to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

this is from documention: [subprocess.Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create
>   the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything other
>   than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or
>   stderr=PIPE too

Answer (score 0):

`1` is the output of your process (`wc -l` in this case). So your print statement is generating the `(None, None)` - if you don't want that, just don't print it.